# How to use Laravel's hasManyThrough across 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 4 tables with a structure and flow like this:

```
User
Accounts
Contacts
Orders
```

The relationship is as follows:

$user->hasMany('accounts')->hasMany('contacts')->hasMany('orders');

```
/** User Model **/
class User extend Eloquent {
    public function accounts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Accounts');
    }

    public function contacts(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Contact', 'Account', 'owner_id');
    }

    //how do I get this?
    public function orders(){

    }
}

/** Account Model */
class Account extends Eloquent {
    public function $user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function contacts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Contact');
    }
}

/** Contact Model **/
class Contact extends Eloquent {
    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Account');
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}

/** Order Model **/
class Order extends Eloquent {
    public function contact(){
        return $this->belongsTo('contact');
    }
}
```

A classic `hasManyThrough` is not possible because we have 4 tables.

How can I create a relationship so that a single user can have it's orders accessed without method chaining each model, such as:

```
User::find(8)->orders;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was quite difficult at first to identify exactly how the query builder slices things together. I knew how I wanted to format the query with a raw SQL statement, but I wanted to use Eloquent for this particular task given the other defined relationships.

I was able to resolve this by overloading the attribute and manually creating the relation. However, the actual query and hasMany needs to be built manually as well. Let's take a look at how I achieved this. Remember, the goal is to get `Orders` off of the user through 2 has-Many relationships.

First, the overloading of the attribute.

```
public function getOrdersAttribute()
{
    if( ! array_key_exists('orders', $this->relations)) $this->orders();

    return $this->getRelation('orders');
}
```

The idea in the above function is to capture when a lazy loaded `->orders` is called. such as `$user->orders`. This checks to see if the `orders` method is in the `relations` array for the existing `User model`. If it's not, then it calls our *next* function in order to populate the relatioship, and finally returns the relationship we've just created.

This is what the function that actually queries the Orders looks like:

```
public function orders()
{
    $orders = Order::join('contacts', 'orders.contact_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
        ->join('accounts', 'contacts.account_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
        ->where('accounts.owner_id', $this->getkey())
        ->get();

    $hasMany = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany(User::query(), $this, 'accounts.owner_id', 'id');

    $hasMany->matchMany(array($this), $orders, 'orders');

    return $this;
}
```

In the above, we tell the Orders table to join it's contacts (which is the established route given the ownership of `belongsTo()` in this scenario). Then from the contacts, we join the accounts, then from the accounts we can get there from our user by matching our `owner_id` column against our existing `$user->id`, so we don't need to do anything further.

Next, we need to manually create our relationship by instantiating an instance of `hasMany` from the `Eloquent Relationship` builder.

Given that the `HasMany` method actually extends the `HasOneOrMany` abstract class, we can reach the `HasOneOrMany` abstract class by passing our arguments directly to `HasMany`, like below:

```
$hasMany = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany(User::query(), $this, 'accounts.owner_id', 'id');
```

The `HasOneOrMany` expects the following to it's constructor:

```
Builder $query,
Model $parent,
$foreignKey, 
$localKey
```

So for our builder query, we've passed an instance of our model that we wish to establish the relationship with, the 2nd argument being an instance of our Model ($this), the 3rd argument being the foreign key constraint from our Current->2nd model, and finally the last argument being the column to match from our current model against the foreign key constraint on our Current->2nd model.

Once we've created our instance of `Relation` from our `HasMany` declaration above, we then need to match the results of the relationship to their many parents. We do this with the `matchMany()` method which accepts 3 arguments:

```
array $models,
Collection $results,
$relation
```

So in this case, the array of models would be an array instance of our current eloquent model (user) which can be wrapped in an array to achieve our effect.

The 2nd argument would be the result of our intitial `$orders` query in our `orders()` function.

Finally, the 3rd argument will be the relation `string` that we wish to use to fetch our instance of this relationship; which for us is `order`.

Now you can correct use either Eloquent or Lazy Loading to fetch our orders for our user.

```
User::find(8)->orders();

$user->orders;
```

Hopefully this is helpful for someone else facing a similar issue.

Comment: You could do this also by extending `HasMany` class and just overriding the method `addConstraints`

Comment: This is a heroic solution that *almost* works, but for some reason the Order models will not have the correct IDs when instantiated. Instead their `id` will be the same as the `contact_id`. At least it is when I tested it on Laravel 5.5. I can't for the life of me figure out why though.

Comment: @JeffPuckett It's been awhile since I implemented this. I almost built a package out of this, too, because there were some nuances, let me revisit this and see if I can figure it out why.

Answer (score 12):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Order::class, [Account::class, Contact::class]);
    }
}
```

Comment: without looking at the source on that project, is this something that could be added to core pretty easy?

Comment: It would be possible, but I strongly doubt it's going to happen. I have no plans to suggest it.

Answer (score 11):

you can through from user to contact then `join` with `Orders`

```
public function orders(){
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Contact', 'Account', 'owner_id')->join('orders','contact.id','=','orders.contact_ID')->select('orders.*');
}
```

It works for me in same case, all feedback welcome

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the model returned will be an instance of `Contact` with all the attributes of an `Order`

Comment: I just needed the `->select('*');` bit at the end to solve my problem of joining the through table to the result table. Thanks!