# Laravel / Eloquent: Is it possible to select all child model data without setting a parent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have various parent/child relationships, drilling down a few levels. What I want to know is if its possible to do something like this:

```
$student = Student::find(1);
$student->bursaries()->enrolments()->courses()->where('course','LIKE','%B%');
```

(With the end goal of selecting the course which is like '%B%'), or if I would have to instead use the DB Query builder with joins?

**Models / Relationships**

Student:

```
public function bursaries() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursary');
}
```

StudentBursary:

```
public function enrolments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursaryEnrolment');
}
```

Comment: Have you gave it a shot?) It was working for me with 2 lvl deep.

Comment: Using php artisan tinker, it failed - but I dont know if its another issue and/or tinker specific: >>> $student->bursaries()->enrolments()->courses()->where('course','LIKE','%B%');
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany::enrolments()'

Comment: Which error you got in Tinker?

Comment: Can you show all the models with those relation methods? By the way, if your DB is not that big, try to get what you need on the DB level. Might be faster anyway.

Comment: Take a read of the `Has Many Through` relationship laravel documentation. I think can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to query **all `courses`**, **from all `enrollments`**, **from all `bursaries`**, **from a `students`**, then, unfortunately, you are one table too many from getting by with the `Has Many Through` relationship, because it supports only 3 tables.

Online, you'll find packages that you can import / or answers that you can follow to provide you more though of solutions, for example:

### 1) [How to use Laravel's hasManyThrough across 4 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228349/how-to-use-laravels-hasmanythrough-across-4-tables)

### 2) https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Anyhow, bellow's something you can do to achieve that with Laravel alone:

```php
// Eager loads bursaries, enrolments and courses, but, condition only courses.
$student = Student::with(['bursaries.enrolments.courses' => function($query) {
    $query->where('course','LIKE','%B%');
}])->find(1);

$enrolments = collect();

foreach($student->bursaries as $bursary)  {
    $enrolments = $enrolments->merge($bursary->enrolments);
}

$courses = collect();

foreach ($enrolments as $enrolment) {
    $courses = $courses->merge($enrolment->courses);
}
```

Comment: great - that works as intended! How do I pass variables to the query though?

Comment: To clarify, the following says $row is undefined in the $query line:         foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $student = Student::with(['bursaries.enrolments.courses' => function($query) {
                $query->where('course','=',$row[3]);
            }])->find($row[0]);
        }

Comment: Nevermind! The answer is to change ```function($query)``` to ```function($query) use ($row) ```

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

When you do `$student->bursaries()` instead of `$student->bursaries`, it returns a `query builder` instead of `relationship map`. So to go to `enrolments()` from `bursaries()` you need to do a `bursaries()->get()`. It should look like this.

`$student->bursaries()->get()[0]->enrolments()`, added the `[0]` because im using `get()`, you can use `first()` to avoid the `[0]`

`$student->bursaries()->first()->enrolments()`
But I'm not sure if it will suffice your requirement or not.

Comment: thanks, while this might work though (havent tried) - its only getting the (first) parent - what I'm asking is if its possible to search through 'all' child records essentially.

Comment: @SupaMonkey if you could mention the relations you have made with your models and what you want to achieve, I could help you

Comment: I have edited the main question to include the relationships. Basically I am trying to select the 'course' that is ' like "%B%" ' from the list of courses the student has.