# Laravel: chained relationships in a verbose way

Tags: laravel, collections, model, relationship

I have several models chained by 1:N relationships:

**User (1 -> N) Asignatura (1 -> N) Clase  (1 -> N) Asiento**

I want to obtain a **collection of Asiento** models, containing all the Asientos of a User.

I tried the "obvious"

`$user->asignaturas->clases->asientos;`

but as `$user->asignaturas` is a collection, `->clases` is not recognized as a valid method (all due relationships, `asignaturas()`, `clases()` and `asientos()` has been created in their respective models)

So I did the following to solve the problem:

```
$user = User::findorFail(Auth::user()->id);
$asignaturasArr = $user->asignaturas->pluck('id')->toArray();
$clases = Clase::whereIn('asignatura_id', $asignaturasArr)->get();
$clasesArr = $clases->pluck('id')->toArray();
$asientos = Asiento::whereIn('clase_id', $clasesArr)->get();
```

but I suspect that Laravel should have a less verbose way to do the work, and I am not being able to find it.

I will be grateful to have any advice from any expert.

Thank you very much in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al last, I think that I found the Eloquent (elegant) solution to the problem. Is the following:

```
$asientos = $user->asignaturas->map->clases->unique()->flatten()->map->asientos->unique()->flatten();
```

Using `map` and `unique()->flatten()` (and, of course, the necessary relationships in the models), you can chain as much relationships levels as you want.

Answer (score 3):

`$user->asignaturas->clases->asientos;` will not work as `asignaturas` is a `collection`, so you would have to do this to work: `$user->asignaturas->first()->clases->first()->asientos;` but you would have to iterate over each `asignaturas` and `clases` and that is for surely not ideal.

So, you could try using [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) but that would also not work 100%, as it only allows `3` level deep, it would only work for `User -> Asignaturas -> Clases` (so you get all User's `Clases` but you would still need to iterate each `Clase` to get every `Asientos`), or it would only work for `Asignaturas -> Clases -> Asientos` (but you would have to write this in `Asignatura` model, not in user, I still think this would work for you).

So, if we use the last one I mentioned, your `Asignatura` model should have this:

```php
class Asignatura extends Model
{
    public function asientos()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Asiento::class, Clase::class);
    }
}
```

Have in mind that this must follow a standard convention, read the documentation about it, and if it is not working, share your models and tables' names so we can help you make it work.

Then, in your `User` model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function asientos()
    {
        $asientos = collect();

        $this->asignaturas->each(function ($asignatura) use ($asientos) {
            $asignatura->asientos->each(function ($asiento) use ($asientos) {
                $asientos->push($asiento);
            });
        });

        return $asientos;
    }
}
```

But, that code is not 100% good, as you are looping a lot, still will work.

Other solution will be to just do a normal query (manually joining) and get the data that way, but I will not do it here as I have no idea what your tables' names are, you can find good tutorials about this, you will have to join tables, really simple to do.

---

Other possible solution you could try using, but I have never used, is using a package that someone created because of this exact problem, it is called [staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep). It can handle `"infinite"` levels instead of just `3`. This is the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127913/1998801) related to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me knowing that there is not a 100% out-of-the.box solution in Laravel (so I can stop searching). Regarding your **first&iterate** solution, I prefer my **pluck&whereIn** one, because seems more elegant and easy to expand (in levels). The hasManyThrough, its a pity the level limitation because at las I also prefer the **pluck&whereIn** solution for the same reason. The package is an interesting possibility, but by the moment I am trying to use only built in Laravel solutions. Thanks a lot @matiaslauriti anyway!